# Changing clock frequency on STM32 without impacting peripherals?

Tags: arm, stm32, firmware

I'm a bit lost with STM32L486 clock management.

I want to change the clock frequency at run-time. Typically I want to be in Low-Power Run/Sleep mode most of the time, and at full frequency the rest of the time.

I know how to set up SysClk either at 80MHz using PLL or at 1MHz using MSI for example.

However the problem is that changing Sysclk is messing up most peripherals setup. For example the USART is not working anymore if I change the clock.

Is it a common practice to do that ( changing the frequency at runtime ) ?

The peripherals I need to use are: LPTIM ( no problem since they can be clocked independantly from SysClk ), ADC, AES accelerator, USART, TIM, SPI.

Comment: unfortunately it is not as simple. Many peripherals have to be reset after the clock change. But usually there is a moment when they are idle (or you cam force them idle).

Comment: Please describe your specific problem. Which peripherals, which clock source etc. You haven't even told what controller do you have.

Comment: @berendi it's more a generic question. On a STM32L4, is it common practice to change the CPU frequency at run time, or is it more usual to set it once for all ? I don't think there is a big difference on this topic between several STM32L4 ? I defined what clock sources I want to use, I will add the peripherals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On STM32L4xx it is not so hard, if you look on "Clock tree" figure in datasheet, many peripherals which are clock dependent (USART, LPTIM, I2C, ..) can be driven with other clock sources than BUS clock, there is also possible to use LSE or internal HSI.

Although internal HSI is not crystal controlled is from my experience enough accurate for UART, also in bigger range of temperatures, but you can tune frequency of this oscillator by comparing its frequency with an external and more accurate clock during runtime, or use auto-buadrate detection.

Comment: the only problem is the increased power consumption, which might be a problem when using low power uC

Comment: What about SPI master ? Is it OK to change SysClk since the STM32 in master mode generates the clock itself anyway ?